# getComputedStyle: wait for external style sheets?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Say you have an external stylesheet (`<link>`), followed by a `<script>`. Is the external stylesheet always applied before the `<script>` executes, so that `getComputedStyle` always respects the external stylesheet's rules?

Or are browsers allowed to run JavaScript before earlier stylesheets have been applied?

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="/my-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <script>
      window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo')).width
      // => "200px" due to stylesheet - is this reliable?
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A practical experiment you can make to test on different browsers: make your "my-stylesheet.css" file huge, adding a couple of Mb of base64 encoded images (so you are sure it will take more time than your slim test page to load), and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: YES this is reliable.

To prove I created following testserver based on nodejs:

Directory:

```
/testserver.js
/server/index.js
/server/style.js
```

`testserver.js` creates a node js server and ensures, that each request takes two seconds to load:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(8888);
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    setTimeout(next, 2000);
});
app.use(express.static('./server'));
```

My `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('mydiv')).width);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `style.css`

```
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff0000;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Now I test it by starting my server and calling `http://localhost:8888/index.html`

In the Chrome developer tools the timeline looks like this:
[image: Timeline]

As you can see the `index.html` file loads before `style.css`

And the Javascript Console outputs `100px` as expected:
[image: Console]

Because of the fact, that there are no errors in js-console and the only output is the expected `100px` I proved that the adoption in question is true.

**EDIT:** Now I tested more:
This works on Chrome with 2s, 5s and 60s => Works!
Furthermore I tested it on Firefox, Opera and Safari with 2s. => Works!

Sorry I've got no IE available.

**EDIT 2:** I just did more research:

The behaviour I figured out is defined by W3C. A loading style file is blocking script execution when it was defined by `link`-tag or `style`-tag:

> A style sheet in the context of the Document of an HTML parser or XML
>   parser is said to be a style sheet that is blocking scripts if the
>   element was created by that Document's parser, and the element is
>   either a style element or a link element that was an external resource
>   link that contributes to the styling processing model when the element
>   was created by the parser, and the element's style sheet was enabled
>   when the element was created by the parser, and the element's style
>   sheet ready flag is not yet set, and, the last time the event loop
>   reached step 1, the element was in that Document, and the user agent
>   hasn't given up on that particular style sheet yet. A user agent may
>   give up on a style sheet at any time.
>
> **Note:**
>    Giving up on a style sheet before the style sheet loads, if the style
>    sheet eventually does still load, means that the script might end up
>    operating with incorrect information. For example, if a style sheet
>    sets the color of an element to green, but a script that inspects the
>    resulting style is executed before the sheet is loaded, the script
>    will find that the element is black (or whatever the default color
>    is), and might thus make poor choices (e.g. deciding to use black as
>    the color elsewhere on the page, instead of green). Implementors have
>    to balance the likelihood of a script using incorrect information with
>    the performance impact of doing nothing while waiting for a slow
>    network request to finish.

[W3C Blocking Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#has-no-style-sheet-that-is-blocking-scripts)

And as defined in [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#stop-parsing) document, in the parsing process the script will not execute until the blocking style has been loaded.

Comment: if i'm on a spotty connection, sometimes stylesheets timeout, or are slow. can you test if the script will wait 5 seconds on the CSS?

Comment: Yeah, but if you expect this the first answer would also not solve the problem. Furthermore the question was if the javascript code runs before css has been applied.

Comment: right, i'm wondering if the script will wait 5 seconds on a slow but not dead stylesheet, or if chrome will grow impatient and execute the script before the sheet loads...

Comment: @DustinHoffner - are you reporting the test results from one version of one browser or do you know that a particular specification requires this behavior such that any compliant browser would block scripts until a prior `<style>` tag was loaded?

Comment: Now I tested in some browsers (see Edit). Proving this for any browser and version is a lot of work. Maybe some W3C Documentation declares this. Would be easier.

Comment: How did you make sure the browser wasn't caching anything?

Comment: Deactivating caching in chrome developer tools. Sorry forgot to mention this. It's my default setting while developer console is open.

Comment: who cares about IE, this is really good info, and good news. it also shed light on not just this issue, but the order of operations in general. good work.

Comment: That's very cool. Is there a spec that mandates this behavior in browsers?

Comment: @dandavis Thanks! :) ... I just did more research. This all is defined by W3C. So it's sure other browsers doing this the same way.

Answer (score 4):

If you want make sure that an external stylesheet has loaded, then you can use the window `load` event which will fire when page resources such as external stylesheets and images have finished loading and the page also will have its final layout:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo')).width
});
```

You can also devise a test to see if the stylesheet has already been loaded by putting a specific and unique style rule in the stylesheet that applies to a specific DOM element (which could even be hidden) and then you can get that style with `getComputedStyle()` and see if it matches what it should be.  If so, then the stylesheet has been loaded.  If not, then the stylesheet has not yet been loaded.  But, if you still need to wait until it's loaded, the the window `load` event is what you would want to use.